# load web pages form Array for iphone

Tags: iphone

i can load web view on button press like this

```
-(void)buttonEvent:(UIButton*)sender{
        NSLog(@"new button clicked!!!");
    if (sender.tag == 1) {




        NSLog(@"1");
    }
    if (sender.tag == 2) {
        NSLog(@"2");

        NSString *path;
        NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];


        path = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"index2" ofType:@"html"];




        NSURL   *instructionsURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];
        [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instructionsURL]];



    }
}
```

but i want to load the path value from my string   `NSString *filepat=[listItems objectAtIndex:2];`
whose value is **tab0/index1.html** where **tab0 is a folder**

so how to load from that string plz help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
// get the app's base directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
// get the dir/filename
NSString *filepat=[listItems objectAtIndex:2];
// concatenate for full path
NSString *filePath = [basePath stringByAppendingString:filepat];
NSURL *instructionsURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instructionsURL]];
```

You could also use a cache like I use - SimpleDiskCache.m - which will fetch URLs from the internet, and cache and fetch them from disk.

```
//  SimpleDiskCache.h

@interface SimpleDiskCache : NSObject { }

+ (void) cacheURL:(NSURL*) url forData:(NSData*)data;
+ (NSData*) getDataForURL:(NSURL*) url;

@end


//  SimpleDiskCache.m

#import "SimpleDiskCache.h"
#import "util.h"

@implementation SimpleDiskCache


+ (NSCharacterSet*) getNonAlphaNumericCharacterSet {
  static NSCharacterSet* cs;
  if (!cs) {
    cs = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    cs = [cs retain];
  }
  return cs;
}

+ (void) cacheURL:(NSURL*) url forData:(NSData*)data {
  NSString* filename = [[[url absoluteString] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                       [NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
  NSString * storePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
  [data writeToFile:storePath atomically:NO];
}


+ (NSData*) getDataForURL:(NSURL*) url {
  NSString* filename = [[[url absoluteString] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                       [NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
  NSString * storePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
  if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
    return [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:storePath]; 
  }
  return nil;
}

@end
```